# Create own software for biometric devices

Tags: c#, biometrics, zkteco

I have a question: I want to know if I have biometric device of zkteco company and I want to create my own software for this device by using c# then how can I do this?

Actually I am a newbie and want to learn. I hope you got my point what I am asking. Thanks

```
<?php
$message = "Thanks in advance for helping";
Echo $message;
?>

<?php
$message = "Thanks in advance for helping";
Echo $message;
?>

<?php
$message = "Thanks in advance for helping";
Echo $message;
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. StackOverflow is for *specific* questions about programming problems - see [ask]. As it stands, this question is too broad. If you went away and tried to write something, and had a problem when doing that, then you could ask a new question about that. It's fine to say thanks, but to then include what appears to be a code snippet, which is actually just saying thanks but takes more space than your actual question is just wasting the time of people volunteering to answer your question. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately for you... There is a member of this community that has written a starting point for communicating with ZKTeco devices in this [Post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104538/Csharp-ZKTeco-Biometric-Device-Getting-Started).

You also have available the official Demo with the sourcecode in this [Link](https://www.zkteco.eu/uploads/ftp/SDK/Standalone%20SDK-Ver6.3.1.34.rar)

Both of these examples are written in C#.

Try to do something yourself, and next time ask a more specific question, since this one is too broad to be asked here.

Hope this helps.